# Error when uploading nativescript/angular 2 iOS application

Tags: ios, typescript, nativescript

Please, someone can help. Since the update of XCODE to 8.1, I get the following error when trying to upload the application to the store : ERROR ITMS-90685: "CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value 'org.nativescript.TNSWidgets' under the iOS application 'careeat.app'."

Comment: perhaps this problem has been related with this issue in Github https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/2182 , where has been reported problem with building NativeScript project with Xcode 8.1. There you will also find possible fix.

Answer (score 0):

@Nikolay Tsonev, not exactly the same error. The one you are taking about can be resolved only on rebooting your mac.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.